# org-mode: Number of items with a specific keyword

Tags: emacs, org-mode

I am a bit new to org customization.

Is there a way to get the number of items with a TODO (or NEXT) keyword in an org document? I found this

https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/App-OrgUtils/bin/count-org-todos

But I would rather have a solution that uses Emacs environment.

EDIT: This seems to do the trick. Not sure if there is a more elegant solution

```
(apply '+ (org-map-entries (lambda () 1) "/TODO|NEXT"))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are right; `org-map-entries` is a great tool to accomplish what.  You might try the alternate syntax per convention, but the form you have is nice and terse.  I personally write that sort of query as:

```
(length (org-map-entries nil "+TODO=\"TODO\"|+TODO=\"NEXT\"" 'file))
```

Comment: Thanks! Can you explain to me what your search expression does? what is "+TODO="?

Comment: It's an alternate more verbose syntax for searching todo keywords specifically (it simply uses the syntax for searching properties).  Both are described here: http://orgmode.org/worg/org-tutorials/advanced-searching.html

Comment: The + form can be used for other special properties as well, e.g. +TAGS="foo". See http://orgmode.org/manual/Matching-tags-and-properties.html#Matching-tags-and-properties for more info.